# How do I remove the active class in the main menu?

Tags: 7

One item in the menu has sub-items that point to the same page (just with different arguments) ex:

Products
- List item 1  \products?pid=1 
- List item 2  \products?pid=2
- List item 3  \products?pid=3

Drupal assigns the "active" class in the

and  tag of the menu items since all the items have the same page url (\products)

I'm overwriting the menu_link function in template.php to remove the active class but the class remains in the  tag

```
function mytheme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {

    if (strtolower($element['#title']) == 'Products') {

      if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
        $currID = $_GET['pid'];

        foreach ($element['#below'] as $Taxonomy) {

          if ($currTaxonomyID != $Taxonomy['#localized_options']['query']['pid']) {
            $mlid = $Taxonomy['#original_link']['mlid'];
            $key = array_search('active', $Taxonomy['#attributes']['class'], TRUE);            
            if ($key) {
              unset($element['#below'][$mlid]['#attributes']['class'][$key]);
              $element['#below'][$mlid]['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][$key] = '';
            }
            // remove active-trail class
            $key = array_search('active-trail', $Taxonomy['#attributes']['class'], TRUE);            
            if ($key) {
              $element['#below'][$mlid]['#attributes']['class'][$key] = '';              
            }
          }          
        }
      }      
    }
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);         
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);  
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Final Result:

```
<ul class="menu nav">
   <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-44253">
      <a href="/products?pid=1" title="Best Practices" class="active">Best Practices</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf menu-mlid-44254">
      <a href="/products?pid=2" title="Checklists" class=" active">Checklists</a>
    </li>
....
```

How can I remove the class "active" from the  tag?

My menu Structure:

```
-Clients
-Products
  -prod1 (url:\\products?pid=1)
  -prod2 (url:\\products?pid=2)
  -prod3 (url:\\products?pid=3)
  -prod4 (url:\\products?pid=4)
-About
```

Comment: Can u send me your menu structure.., It will helps in solving the program fast.

Comment: -Clients
-Products
  -prod1 (url:\\products?pid=1)
  -prod2 (url:\\products?pid=2)
  -prod3 (url:\\products?pid=3)
  -prod4 (url:\\products?pid=4)
-About

Comment: This will NEVER evaluate `if (strtolower($element['#title']) == 'Products') {
`  Fix it and it may work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: [the l() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7.x) automatically assigns an `active` class when a link is pointing to the current page.

I got around this using an (ugly) hack:

[As noted in the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7.x), `$options['language']` is additionally compared with `$language_url->language` before assigning the `active` class.

So, the hack is to supply a *deliberately incorrect* language when calling `l()`.

You can find out what the current language of your site is using dpm():

```
global $language_url;
dpm($language_url->language);
```

In my case, I know that the language of the site is *definitely not* `und`, so I appended `array('language' => 'und')` to my call to `l()`:

`l('link text', 'path/to/page', array('language' => 'und'))`

After this, the `a` element no longer had the `active` class.

Comment: He just has a bug in his code `if (strtolower($element['#title']) == 'Products')`.  I think when/if he fixes(d) that it should be fine.